# How do I resolve IMPORTHTML showing only table headers

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://shimdu.com/free/survey.html","table",1)
```

Returning only the table headers and not the content. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0):

not possible to resolve. everything under a header is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't work with JavaScript at all. you can test this by disabling JS, by clicking on the lock next to URL in address bar and selecting Site settings and there disabling JS.