# Scraping data from fivethirtyeight RAPTOR stat

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, web-scraping

I tried all types of imports, and can't get all the data into google sheets.

[image: google sheets]

[image: google sheets]

Comment: Did the solution from Bryan work for you @filreal? It did for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the data from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/nba-raptor/modern_RAPTOR_by_player.csv:

```
=IMPORTDATA(A1)
```

[image]

This will get you the raw data saved in that link and you'd need to filter it using other formulas based on your needs.

For the second case, table at the URL https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/nba-player-ratings/ is generated using JavaScript, [as mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518362/19602805), Google Sheets cant import JS elements.